# Biztalk Composite Operations Service

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I need to consume a Biztalk service that contains some composite operations. Essentially, one of my entities is in the form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://HRMApplication.Schemas.Customer" targetNamespace="http://HRMApplication.Schemas.Customer" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CustomerCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Active" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="SubNumber" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="CustomerAccountNumber" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="AccountBranchCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="BranchLocationCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Attention" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Addresses">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Street1" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Street2" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PhoneNumbers">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PhoneNumber" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="PhoneType" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

On the client side, I need to create a proxy for my service, and then create requests passing in customer objects and then displaying the response from the server in c#. How do I go about doing this in code please? Essentially, I am looking for code sample to help start me off of how to handle this sort of scenario given that when I generate a proxy using the ADD SERVICE REFERENCE option in visual studio, I get a proxy that requires I create a request object and then expect a response object.

Answer (score 0):

Even within BizTalk, your composite operation will be wrapped around the response object. Your customer element will probably be created within the response object. The response object name and namespace is usually defined in the Adapter. What type of adapter are you using?

Comment: I am using the WCF-Adapter here.